# What is the role of the refresh token flow within the modern authentication/authorization space?

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, openid-connect

I am having some trouble grasping the role of the refresh token flow within modern SAML/OAuth/OIDC methods.

I understand that *authentication* is about proving a user is who they say they are, while *authorization* is about proving a user has access to any particular resource. I also understand that refresh tokens can be used to to handle both.

My question is, how does the refresh/access token flow fit within authentication/authorization methods like OAuth2.0 and OIDC? Is it a subset of these auth methods, or just an optional technique sometimes employed by them? Or are they unrelated to and are like comparing pineapples to oranges?

When it comes to building authentication into a system using the refresh token flow, it is not considered OAuth or OIDC unless if it is built to [specifications defined here](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749), correct?

edit: To be more succinct - OAuth seems like a "complete" authentication method. Is the refresh token flow also considered a "complete" solution alongside OAuth, or is it just a technique that is used within OAuth?

Comment: OpenID Connect is a layer on top of oAuth 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

When the user has authenticated and got the *access token*, it will **expire** after a pre-configured time (e.g. 10 minutes). But to keep the user signed in longer than the expiration time, a *refresh token* can be used to request a new *access token* (e.g. valid for additional 10 minutes), and you typically also get a new *refresh token*.

In other words, the *refresh token* is a way to keep the "user session" alive for longer than the expiration time of an *access token*.

A *refresh token* typically have different security properties, e.g. it can typically only be *used one time*.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of the refresh token flow. I'm familiar with idea of refresh token rotation and re-issuing a new one for every access token request. I'm guess I'm just confused on its role in relation to OAuth. OAuth seems like a "complete" authentication method. Is the refresh token flow also considered a "complete" solution alongside OAuth, or is it just a technique that is used within OAuth?

Comment: The refresh token is a part of OAuth, yes. OAuth is not an authentication method, more a "delegation protocol" - but OpenID Connect is an authentication protocol built upon OAuth 2.